# [django,AWS S3 problem]An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied

Tags: python-3.x, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am trying to make a django gallery site using S3 bucket.
I followed the tutorial on youtube
It worked well locally but didnt work on EC2.
I have checked the IAM user access id and secret key and they are correct.
I made a new access key but didnt work.

## Errror Message

```
(...)
Exception Type: ClientError at /gallery/add/
Exception Value: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied
```

## Settings.py

(couldnt upload it looked like spam)

## S3 Policy

```json
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::photoshare20230619/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

## IAM User

[ScreenShot of IAM User](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MEfZ.png)

## My buddy's Summary

(because I worked with AI)

You're running a Django application on a server using Gunicorn and Nginx. The application includes a feature to upload photos, which are then stored in an Amazon S3 bucket. However, you're encountering a few issues:

You're getting a Server Error (500) from Django. The error logs indicate that this is due to an AccessDenied error when the application tries to put an object in the S3 bucket. You've confirmed that the IAM user has the AmazonS3FullAccess policy and the bucket policy allows the IAM user to put objects. The access keys are also correctly set in your Django settings.

You've noticed that the IAM user's console access is disabled, but you're not sure if this is related to the issue.

You've created the access keys for the IAM user by selecting "Programmatic access". You're not sure if this is correct or if you should have selected "AWS Management Console access".

You've checked and confirmed that the access keys are correct in your Django settings. You've also tried changing the bucket policy to explicitly allow the IAM user to put objects, but the issue persists.

You're considering asking for help on StackOverflow as you're not sure how to resolve this issue.

Tried using another S3 bucket -> didnt work

tried using differnt access keys -> didnt work

Comment: All of the codes are here: [github](https://github.com/Chloro989/AWS2022-10-24/tree/main)

Comment: followed this tutorial https://youtu.be/sSquD2u5Ie0

Comment: settings.py here: https://github.com/Chloro989/AWS2022-10-24/blob/main/website/website/settings.py

Comment: Your S3 policy only contains `s3:GetObject` but not `s3:PutObject`.

Comment: Changed the policy but still gets the erorr

Comment: ```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::photoshare20230619/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: May you also need to add `s3:PutObjectAcl`. Your new policy does not include the asterisks anymore `"arn:aws:s3:::photoshare20230619/"`. Why do you remove that? It means you can only act (get/add) on this exact single location.

Comment: added `s3:PutObjectAcl`. There are still asterisks. Dissappered in the comment

Comment: still getting the same erorr

Comment: Thank you for your support, I solved this by moving to Azure storages.